# Error when declaring variable in if statement

Tags: php

I'm having a parse error when I upload this code on my server (php 5.5.12):

```
if (!empty($a = $b)) {...}
```

The error is :

> syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

I don't have any problem with the same code on MAMP (php 5.5.10).
Of course I can easily solve it with this code:

```
$a = $b;    
if (!empty($a)) {...}
```

But well, the first one should work.

Thank you!

EDIT :
I works. I just had a problem with my PHP version.

Comment: Are you sure your server is 5.5.12 ? I don't think it is

Answer (score 5):

From the [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty) docs:

> **Note**: Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty()` only supports variables; anything else
>   will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not
>   work: `empty(trim($name))`. Instead, use `trim($name) == false`.

Comment: `5.5.0 empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.`

Comment: if you have php 5.5  which unless build from source is unlikely you have, most package managers ship 5.3 or 5.4

Answer (score 1):

you can't put a variable assignment inside `empty`... as a shot in the dark, i guess you mean to do a comparison between `$a` and `$b`... in which case try using `==` or `===` to compare type also.

**EDIT** prior to PHP5.5 you will have to assign the comparison to a variable:

```
$expr = $a == $b;
if (!empty($expr)) {...}
```

HOWEVER, i'm not really sure why you need to use empty here... could just do

```
if (FALSE !== ($a == $b)) {...}
```

Comment: No I don't want to make the comparison. And Yes you can make a variable assignment empty(), and in simple if () {} statements.

Comment: ok then you should definitely be setting the variable prior to empty... just for good code readability.

Comment: We actually get used to it, it doesn't bother me for readability and I think we'll see more and more of that. In a lot of languages.

Comment: hmm, don't know, comparison and things i can see, but assignment, a quick glance and it will look like its supposed to be a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function `empty()` simply checks to see if a variable is both set (`isset()` and is not not NULL (!is_null()). In PHP versions older than 5.5, you cannot evaluate an expression inside it.

Edit:

Removed the code snippets because they were a little confusing. The second snippet in the original question is correct. The bit above should explain why.

Comment: Yes, and I'm telling him he has to use that form for it to work. Sorry, I'll edit to make that a little clearer. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine, you can check into next [url](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ee2afa5c3dddc283b69ee9d510695acf7deb451)

```
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ee2afa5c3dddc283b69ee9d510695acf7deb451
```

Maybe your server have some bad settings. Make sure you have the full version 5.5.12

Comment: Yes, that came from my php version. I didn't reboot my server after updating php. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't reboot my server after updating php to 5.5.x. My bad.

But it works!

Thank you!